# Save data from AEM to Asp.Net Site by API

Tags: adobe, aem, assets

Requirements:

- We want to create two sites. One in AEM and one in asp.net
- In AEM site we want to create assets and contents(articles or stories with title, detail and assets). Content page uses specific template like Title, Detail, Image, Video etc
- Asp.net site uses MSSQL which has table with columns like Title, Detail, ImagePath, VideoPath etc
- Now our requirement is when user create any new Content in AEM site it must be created in ASP.net site. We want to save data from AEM site to ASP.Net site’s database by API
- Same behavior should happened for delete and update the Contents.

Questions:

1. Is above requirement possible?
2. If above requirement is possible then how to know content data changed? For example, if I change only title then how can I know title is only changed?
3. If asset is changed in content then how to know which asset changed in content page?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Is above requirement possible?

Yes.

> 2. If above requirement is possible then how to know content data changed? For example, if I change only title then how can I know title is only changed?

You could create a workflow launcher to kick off a process to upload the content to the .NET site's database when nodes are added/modified.

> 3. If asset is changed in content then how to know which asset changed in content page?

Not entirely sure what you're asking here but I believe the same solution as 2) applies.

More information:

https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-3/administer/operations/workflows/starting.html#Workflow%20Launchers

UPDATE:
Do I believe this is a good idea? No :)

Comment: Is there any other way?

Comment: the solution I proposed doesn't meet your requirements?